# How to apply case Insensitive filter

Tags: python, csv

So I have CSV1:

```
Name, City, Country  
David, Los Angeles, US    
Peter, Chicago, US  
Mark, Chicago, US  
Brian, New York, US  
Paul, Los Angeles, US  
Andy, Boston, US  
Chris, Dallas, US
```

And CSV2:

```
City, Name, Country  
PETER, Chicago, US  
Adam, Florida, US  
MARK, Chicago, US  
James, Austin, US  
BRIAN, New York, US
```

I want to remove redundant names. It doesn't matter what the City and Country are, because I only have to write the names to the output csv file. So in this case, for BRIAN and brian it will remove the redundant data and take only one name (brian). At the same time, I want the data('Name') that is CSV1 but not in CSV2, to be printed to the output file as well. So, basically, it is a case insensitive filter. Something like this:

```
Name:
David  
Peter  
Mark  
Brian   
Paul  
Andy    
Chris
```

I have tried this code:

```
import csv

# load second file as lookup table
data2 = {}
data1 = {}
with open('CSV2.csv', 'r') as csvinput:
    reader = csv.reader(csvinput)
    for row in csvinput:
        data2[row[1]] = row

# now process first file against it
with open("CSV1.csv", 'r') as lookuplist:
    reader1 = csv.reader(lookuplist)
    for col in lookuplist:
        data1[col[0]] = col
        if col[0] not in data2:
            print(col[0])
        if col.lower()[0] == data2.lower()[1]:
            print('Matches')
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I know there is something wrong with the list that I'm creating but I am not able to figure out if it is actually comparing lowercase of both the columns and printing the MATCHES as I want to verify it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no need to import csv, as you can easily extract the information by splitting on the comma. Also, it might be preferable to add a check so that 'Name' is not considered like a valid name.

I don't know if that's a requirement, but say you needed to filter with a third file, I prefer to define a function we can call with parameters to build an unduped list right away.

```
def build_unduped_names(names_repository, file_name):
    with open(file_name) as csvinput:
        for row in csvinput:
            exploded_row = row.split(',')
            if exploded_row[0].lower() == 'name':
                continue
            names_repository[exploded_row[0].lower()] = True


file_names = [
    'CSV1.csv',
    'CSV2.csv',
]

unduped = {}
for file_name in file_names:
    build_unduped_names(unduped, file_name)

print(set(unduped))
```

Comment: This one helped me with the logic that I needed and closely aligned with my script, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For one thing

```
if col.lower()[0] == data2.lower()[1]:
```

Should be:

```
if col[0].lower() == data2[1].lower():
```

That is what is causing the error

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

**EDIT**

To solve KeyError mentioned in comments:

```
for k, v in data2:
    if data2[k].lower() == col[0].lower():
        print('Matches')
```

You could also just compare by the variable v (representative of each value in the dict), but I used accessing the index by key for clarity on that functionality.

Comment: data2 is a dictionary, it doesn't have the Key 1. You're assigning each index of data2 to row[1], you'll need to access it using each value assigned earlier from row[1].

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
csv1names = [(line.split()[0]).title() for line in csv1file]
csv2names = [(line.split()[0]).title() for line in csv2file]

filtered = [name if name not in csv2names for name in csv1names]
```

Then, you can simply write the contents of `filtered` to your file.

Comment: For the last line: `set(csv1names + csv2names)`

Comment: @user3483203 Wouldn't work because names in csv2 which aren't in csv1 would also be included, which isn't what OP wants (look at Adam in the OP's example)

Comment: Then why is he even reading the second file if he takes no names from it?

Comment: @user3483203 (S)he's using the second file as a blacklist; any names which are in the second file aren't wanted.

Comment: Then why is Brian in the desired output? Or Mark or Peter?

Comment: @user3483203 Hmmmmm ... now that I think about it, your logic seems right!

Comment: @user3483203 Comment on OP's question?

Comment: It's the question that's unclear, it seems as though the second file as has no effect on the outcome :D

Comment: @user3483203 You're right :D Essentially, the OP just wants a `.title()`ed version of all of the names in the first file, so there's no need for the second file.

Comment: okay I think i was not able to clearly explain the idea here, so csv1 has data of about 400+ entries and csv2 has more than 10000. I have to print values which are in csv1 but not in csv2. At the same time, there are redundant entries in csv1 which are not in csv2 but they should be printed only once. Got it?

Comment: My aim here is to apply lower case to both the respective columns in those 2 csvs and match and write their differences.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('location/filename.csv')
df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: x.capitalize())
print(df['Name'].unique()) #Now you will get all the unique names.
```

Write these names to your required csv file

Comment: I am not using pandas. would be nice if you could provide a solution without using pandas here.